# Oracle SQL - Add a column with data not included in any table

Tags: sql, oracle

I have this query:

```
Select
Trunc(Red.Fulfilled_Dtime),
P.Email,
(Red.Points_Deducted *.003)*(1/1.02) As Redeem_Amt,
Red.Player_Id,
Red.Prize_Id, 
Red.Points_Deducted
From Redemption_Log Red
Inner Join Player P On Red.Player_Id=P.Player_Id
Where Red.Prize_Id In (8907,8906,8905,8904,8903,8902,8901)
```

I want to add a column to my result called "Currency" in which every row in my results has the output "USD". Is this possible?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can add `virtual column` on your `SELECT` statement,

```
SELECT  Trunc(Red.Fulfilled_Dtime),
        P.Email,
        (Red.Points_Deducted *.003)*(1/1.02) As Redeem_Amt,
        Red.Player_Id,
        Red.Prize_Id, 
        Red.Points_Deducted,
        'USD' AS "Currency"                            -- <<== virtual column
FROM    Redemption_Log Red
        Inner Join Player P 
            On Red.Player_Id=P.Player_Id
WHERE  Red.Prize_Id In (8907,8906,8905,8904,8903,8902,8901)
```

Comment: +1, but that's not a "virtual column". THIS is a virtual column: http://www.oracle-base.com/articles/11g/virtual-columns-11gr1.php